# Calculate %change from array values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have below code that creates array:

```
$query = $conn->query("select step1 FROM workflow1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 4;");

$array = Array();
while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $array[] = $result['step1'];
}

print_r($array);
```

**Present Output:** Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 52 [3] => 10 )

How can I find percentage change in array values? i.e. what I want is

**Desired output:** ((1-2)/2) -> -50%, ((2-52)/52) -> -96.15%  and so on. I going to put it in html table.

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself? btw, some databases give you this functionality....

Comment: I have got another query: `SELECT x.id, x.step1, (((x.step1 / y.step1) - 1) * 100) AS 'Change_1' FROM ( SELECT a.id AS aid, MAX(b.id) AS aPrevid FROM workflow1 a INNER JOIN workflow1 b WHERE a.id > b.id GROUP BY a.id ) Sub1 INNER JOIN workflow1 x ON Sub1.aid = x.id INNER JOIN workflow1 y ON Sub1.aPrevid = y.id ORDER BY x.id DESC` which directly gives percemtage. Plz help how can I store its output in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$array = [1, 2, 52, 10];
$change = [];
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  if(count($array) - 1 > $key) {
    $prev = $array[$key];
    $next = $array[++$key];    
    $percent_key = "((".$prev."-".$next.")/".$next.")";    
    $percent_value = (($prev-$next)/$next)*100;
  }
 $change[$percent_key] = $percent_value;
}
print_r($change);
```

Output:

> Array ( [((1-2)/2)] => -50 [((2-52)/52)] => -96.153846153846 [((52-10)/10)] => 420 )

Comment: Just one more query, as Keys will be changing, how can I print say 1st value in array, say 50?

Comment: I could get values and print using code where 0 is 1st element: `<?php 
echo $change[array_keys($change)[0]];
?>`

Comment: Also, you can use multidimentional array like: `$change["key"] = $percent_key;` `$change["value"] = $percent_value;`   
    `$output[] = $change;` `print_r($output[0]["value"]);`

Comment: OK.Thank you, but above single line code does the sane trick, so will use that as I an putting it inside TD tag.

Comment: this does not support 0 in the array. I think we could use: $percent_value = $next === 0 ? 0 : (($prev-$next)/$next)*100;

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$datas = array( 0 => 1 ,1 => 2, 2 => 52 ,3 => 10 );

$output= array();

foreach ($datas as $key=>$value){
    $output[]= (($key-$value)/$value)*100;
}

print_r($output);
```

this is the output :

> Array ( [0] => -100 [1] => -50 [2] => -96.153846153846 [3] => -70 )

Comment: Yeah, this what I was looking for, but I didn't get how -100 and -70 is result. From database query result is: -50, -96.15384615384616, 420 and -80.76923076923077.

Comment: i think -100 is the result of the first one : ((0-1)/1)*100 = -1*100 =-100 ;
-70 ======> (3-10/10)*100= (7/10)*100= 0.7*100=70 
this is wrong ?